# React Native, support for Windows Phone and BlackBerry

Tags: react-native

Does React Native have support for Windows Phone and BlackBerry? Perhaps Java Phones too (Jad and Jar). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can build react native apps for the Windows platform, including windows mobile phones and X-Box:

https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2016/05/26/creating-universal-windows-apps-with-react-native/

There doesn't appear to be any support for Blackberry, however.

And... I wouldn't recommend building any apps for the Windows platform, as it's basically dead: https://www.theverge.com/2017/10/9/16446280/microsoft-finally-admits-windows-phone-is-dead

Answer (score 1):

There is a reNative project that aim to bring react native to wide variety of devices take a look at that

https://renative.org/

Answer (score 0):

No. React Native supports Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try react native app built android.

APK can be installed on blackberry.